# Is this sentence correct - I hope I wasted as much of your time as you did mine

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, expressions

I have got this sentence

> I hope I wasted as much of your time as you did mine.

In this sentence using word **I hope** here I am confused, why because I hope is kind of positive word but the sentence is negative. Or it is correct

Comment: One can hope for negative things or neutral things as well as for positive ones.

Comment: @CowperKettle - Thank you for your input. But if I say "I hope I have wasted your time", It seems I came to waste your time intentionally & now I am feeling happy. There is no feeling of kind of regret.

Comment: It's called **schadenfreude** and is not an uncommon human emotion.

Comment: @RonaldSole - Thank you. I agree. But what would be the answer of my question. If am not happy by wasting somebody time than how should I say it.

Comment: @Arvindraja I hope that I have **not** wasted as much of your time as you did (of) mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Hope" expresses what someone wants, desires, or wishes, regardless of whether those things are generally considered negative or positive.** For example, it would be idiomatic to say, "I hope he dies."

In your example, if someone wasted your time, and you would prefer that you also wasted their time, then you could say:

> I hope I wasted as much of your time as you did mine.

This may not mean that you are exactly *happy* about the situation, but it could give you some spiteful satisfaction.